# String concatenation for row.field from CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I am trying to dynamically create the name of a field in a CSV that I am parsing using `FOREACH`.

I am trying this:

```
// From Load CSV 
WITH row,
    ['NAME-A', 'NAME-B'] AS olink_panels
FOREACH (panel in olink_panels |
    MERGE (p:Plate      {plate_id:  row["Prefix $panel-Suffix"], 
                        name:       panel})
)
```

Neo4j is parsing the code but not creating any new nodes. I suspect it is not evaluating the `$panel` variable.

Comment: Could the nodes already exist? If this executed successfully once then it's likely it's just matching to existing nodes rather than finding none and creating them instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `panel` to generate a header name, this should work:

```
FOREACH (panel in ['NAME-A', 'NAME-B'] |
    MERGE (p:Plate     {plate_id:  row["Prefix " + panel + "-Suffix"], 
                        name:      panel})
)
```

The `$panel` syntax (with the starting dollar sign) should only be used if `panel` was passed to the query as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). And Cypher would not do parameter substitution within string literals anyway.

Comment: That makes sense about the `$panel` syntax. I tried your suggestion @cybersam and it parses, but does not create the nodes. There are no :Plate nodes in my graph before or after running the code. I put the array outside of the FOREACH block and aliased it it with any success. It is like the alias for `row` and `panel` are not being evaluated or are out of scope somehow.

Comment: Can you add to your question what the first 3 or so lines in your CSV file look like?

Comment: In trying to understand why the `panel` variable is not being evaluated, tried the following:
```
    // Sample -> Batch
    WITH row
    MATCH (s:Sample         {barcode:   row.Patient_Group})
    MATCH (b:Batch          {name:      row.Batch})
    MERGE (s)-[:HAS_BATCH]->(b)

    WITH ['A', 'B'] as tests, row
    FOREACH (test in tests |
        MERGE (t:TEST {name: test})
    )```
 the FOREACH block is run after the last MERGE. The FOREACH block in is the same location in my code, at the end. It does not eval `test`. If I run FOREACH block by itself it does eval `test`.

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting...I'll try to fix. Unfortunately I can not share any records from the file. I am successfully building nodes and relationships from rows in the file. Just getting hung up on the FOREACH loop. I also tried UNWIND.

Comment: If a `MATCH` clause fails to match, then the entire query is aborted. That is apparently what is causing your issue. Your question  should have provided your entire query.

Comment: I should have posted the query, but I think the issue is more to do with the FOREACH suboutine. The reason I suspect this is when I run this code all properties are created except `val`.

Comment: `FOREACH (panel in panels |
    //MERGE (p:Plate      {plate_id:  row["Olink " + panel + "-Plate ID"]}) 
    //ON CREATE SET p.name = panel
    MERGE (t:DEBUG)
    SET t.sex   = row.SEX
    SET t.panel = panel
    SET t.val   = row["Olink " + panel + "-Plate ID"]
)`

Comment: Comments in Stackoverflow omit all line breaks, so I do not know where your Cypher comment lines end and therefore do not know what your actual queries look like. For example, in your comment from 20 hours ago, I do not know if the `MATCH` clauses are commented out. Can you amend your Question?